# How to work on an angular app from multiple machines

Tags: angular

I am working on an angular app on my school laptop and I want to be able to work on it on my personal laptop. I pushed the app to a repo and got the repo on my personal laptop. I downloaded all the angular pre-requisites, but when I do ng serve on my personal laptop I get the following error:

```
Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "C:\\my-app".
Error: Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "C:\\my-app".
    at Object.resolve (C:\Users\tanne\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node\resolve.js:141:11)
    at Observable.rxjs_1.Observable [as _subscribe] (C:\Users\tanne\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\src\architect-legacy.js:153:40)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (C:\Users\tanne\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:44:25)
    at Observable.subscribe (C:\Users\tanne\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:30:22)
    at C:\Users\tanne\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:99:19
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Observable.toPromise (C:\Users\tanne\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:97:16)
    at ServeCommand.initialize (C:\Users\tanne\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:130:86)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:757:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

What do I need to do to be able to work on my angular app on multiple machines?

Comment: did you try to install the missing dependency?  `npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Clone the repository using "git clone ...." command.
2. Make sure you have installed NodeJS already.
3. Inside the project directory, where you see package.json, run "npm install" command.
4. Run "npm install -g @angular/cli" to install ng cli.
5. Run "ng serve" command.

Hope this helps. All the best.

Comment: He might also need/want to install angular global.  `npm i -g @angular/cli`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. yes, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. First install NodeJs in your school computer.
2. Then open a terminal and run "npm install"
3. Then "ng serve"